# ROR nesting content_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Hopefully there is someone out there that can help me. I have made a helper method which is supposed to output a checkbox (which is either checked or not depending on the player),
a picture of the player and the name of the player. Unfortunately the only thing that is outputted is the checkbox. I am just getting empty li's.
here is the code:

```
def add_players_and_checkboxes(game_id,user)

  boolean = 0 

  find_all_players(game_id).each do |p| 
  boolean = true if user.id == p.id 
end 

output = content_tag :div, :class => "span2" do 
  concat(content_tag :li, add_check_box(user,game_id,boolean))
  concat(content_tag :li) do 
    concat(content_tag :ul) do
      concat(content_tag :li) do
      concat(image_tag(user.picture, :height => '50px',:alt => 'user_pic'), :class         =>"picture")
      end
      concat(content_tag :li, user.first_name, :class => "name")
    end
  end 
end

return output
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
output = content_tag :div, :class => "span2" do
  content_tag(:li, add_check_box(user,game_id,boolean)) +
  content_tag(:li) do
    content_tag(:ul) do
      content_tag(:li) do
        image_tag user.picture, :height => '50px', :alt => 'user_pic', :class => "picture"
      end +
      content_tag(:li, user.first_name, :class => "name")
    end
  end 
end
```

Comment: the problem was the spaces between content_tag and the (:li). With that removed, everything works.